# Copy and Paste symbology in Raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, symbology, raster-calculator

[image]

I am trying to figure it out how can I take a preserved color from a raster I already set up before and then apply the colormap to a new raster file?

Here are the details of what occurred:
Before I export it to a Imagine file, the shade relief was in grid file and I change the color ramp and made the edits of the colors I want and save it the style in Arcmap 10.
When my ArcGIS 10 was installed last December 2012 and in about a month or so my ArcGIS 10 had problem, so I had to re-install my ARCGIS 10 to correct a problem.
Now that my style file I saved the color I want got lost/ or missing and could not find it. Is there a way that can I get the colors from the raster I have and to apply a new shade relief?

This is the picture I want the colors to transfer to another raster.

as of May 1, 2013 my ArcGIS has been upgraded to 10.1 .

Answer (score 1):

I hope to understand you . If you want to save the symbology and then use it to another layer or the same layer in other time you should use save as layer file option.

1. Right click to the raster and click Save As Layer File. save layer file
2. Open properties of another raster
3. select Symbology tab
4. Click Import buttom
5. Navigate to the saved layer file and select the layer file
6. Click Ok. Click Ok

Comment: This will not work since it has three bands. The only way to do that is from a band.

Comment: Try use raster dataset,raster catalog or mosaic dataset and see this link. I don't try this method but i think it's helpful :   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000024q000000

Comment: I dont have 10.1 at the moment so I am using 10.0 currently.

Comment: @PROBERT Save As layer File work with three bands.Do you try it?

Comment: Does not matter it will not work.